# Visual studio - Docker Compose Remove the custom name to scale the service

Tags: visual-studio, docker-compose

I've a solution in visual studio with docker support.

I'm trying to add a scale property on it to make some tests in our application.
Here is my docker compose file

```yaml
version: '3.4'
name: legacy-mongo-campaign-watcher
services:
  application.worker.watcher:
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}applicationworkerwatcher
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Application/Worker/Application.Worker.Watcher/Dockerfile
```

But when I try to debug the application the following error appears:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   DT1001  WARNING: The "application.worker.watcher" service is using the custom container name "Application.Worker.Watcher". Docker requires each container to have a unique name. Remove the custom name to scale the service.
> If the error persists, try restarting Docker Desktop.   docker-compose  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets   412

Any ideas?